# Making interpolations in a 4D matrix

Tags: performance, matlab

I have Matlab code that is very inefficient and I need to run it several times. 
The code is basically a big `parfor` loop which I guess there is almost impossible to get around.

The code starts by loading several parameters and 4-D matrices, and then needs to make a few interpolations. All need to be done 5000 times (thus the `parfor` loop).

I simplified the code the most I could without taking out the key ingredients.

```
load file

nsim = 5000
T = 12; 
N = 1000;

cumQx = cumsum(Qx);
cumQz = cumsum(Qz);
cumQs = cumsum(Qs);

for k=1:nsim
st(k).ksim    = kstar*ones(N, T);
st(k).Vsim  = zeros(N,T);  
st(k).Psim = zeros(N,T);   
end


parfor k = 1:nsim    

    sysrand  = rand(T, 1);
    idiorand = rand(N, T);
    sigmarand = rand(T,1);

    xid = zeros(T, 1);
    zid = zeros(N, T);
    sid = zeros(T,1);
    xid(1) = 8;
    zid(:, 1) = 5;
    sid(1) = 1;
    % Initializing the simulation

    simx    = zeros(T,1);
    zsim    = ones(N,T)*zbar;
    simsx    = zeros(T,1);

    % Construct 3-D grid using 'ndgrid'
    [ks,zs] = ndgrid(kgrid,z);

    for j = 2:T
            sid(j) = find(cumQs(:, sid(j-1)) >= sigmarand(j), 1); 
            simsx(j-1) = sigmax(sid(j));

             xid(j) = find(cumQx(:, xid(j-1)) >= sysrand(j), 1); 
             simx(j-1) = x(xid(j));

             for n = 1:N
                 zid(n, j)   = find(cumQz(:, zid(n, j-1)) >= idiorand(n, j), 1); 
                 zsim(n,j-1) = z(zid(n, j));
             end
            st(k).ksim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),   st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % K
            st(k).Vsim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % V
            st(k).Psim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % P


    end; 

end
```

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/file_406) is a link for the matrices needed to run the code. Also a dropbox link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gxlhzs686x991t/file.mat?dl=0).

Is there any better way of doing this that would significantly reduce the computation time? My guess is no.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Have you tried the profiler? Which lines are most time consuming?

Comment: I would like to look at this, but I don't like the filedropper-link. I'm quite sure it's harmless, but I can't tell just by looking at the filename.

Comment: Maybe a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gxlhzs686x991t/file.mat?dl=0

Comment: Also there is a bounty on Stackoverflow for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986616/improve-efficiency-matlab